# Existence of infimum of the definition of a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

In $\mathbb{R}$, define $\lambda(U):=\sum (b_k-a_k)$ where $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ is an open set and $U=\cup I_k$, and each $I_k=(a_k, b_k)$ is an open interval.

Now define a set function $\mu(A):=\inf\{\lambda(U):A\subset U, U\subset\mathbb{R}:open\}$.

I can feel this definition measures the size of a set $A$ in terms of the "size" of an open set $U$ closest to the set $A$, but I'm uncertain whether the infimum exists or not.

Since the sequence of numbers $\lambda(U)$ are decreasing as $U$ approaches to $A$, if the lower bound exists, then we can tell the limit exists.

Since $\lambda:O(\mathbb{R})\to [0,+\infty]$, where $O(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$, we have the lower bound $0$. but I don't feel this fact is sufficient.

Can you explain me this rigorously?

Comment: For **every** non-empty $B\subseteq[0,\infty]$ the $\inf B$ exists with $\inf B\in[0,\infty]$. The only special case is $B=\{\infty\}$ where $\inf B$ exists but is not an element of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from the fact that every non-empty subset of $[0,\infty]$ has an infimum.

If every $U$ containing $A$ has infinite measure, then this subset will contain only infinity, and by definition the infimum is infinity.

If there is some $U$ with finite measure that contains $A$, then you can disregard those with infinite measure, so we are talking about the infimum of a non-empty subset of $[0,\infty)$. This infimum exists and is non-negative by the axioms that define $\mathbb R$ in the first place.